# Error in gridview when allowPaging = true - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-index-changed

i have gridview in my asp.net webform.

i bind my database to gridview like this:

```
SQL = "SELECT id,Fname,Lname FROM MEN";
dsView = new DataSet();
adp = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, Conn);
adp.Fill(dsView, "MEN");
adp.Dispose();
GridView1.DataSource = dsView.Tables[0].DefaultView;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

and this i put in the gridview: `allowPaging = true`

its show the data in the grid, but if i press to page 2..3..

and i got this error:

```
The GridView 'GridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The GridView 'GridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled.
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to handle the [PageIndexChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanging.aspx) event, if you click the grid on the designer and look at the events, double click on the PageIndexChanging event, if you don't need to cancel or do anything special, just rebind the data in the handler

Comment: The code you posted that does the data binding - put it in a method, and invoke it in the event.

Comment: i try this - but i see the same records and not the next 10..20..records

Comment: I have the exact same problem @ Gali, still displays the same records

Answer (score 3):

You Should just add the namespace

using System.Collections.Generic;

and write this code only

```
public void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGridview();
}
```

it 100% works try it......

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide an event handler for PageIndexChanging, which is where you provide the paging logic.

Answer (score 0):

write like this in `GridView1_PageIndexChanging` event:

```
GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
```

then again bind the grid.
ur prob will solve.